# Evaluate HTML5 data attribute - How to handle quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I am trying to use custom data attribute

```
<span class="k-nav-day" data-dt="kendo.toString(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')">

</span>
```

But when i try below code in JavaScript,

```
  var dateOfHeader = $(this).data("dt");
```

It still gives me in quotes and its not getting evaluated

```
  "kendo.toString(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')"
```

It should have formatted the 'date' and date should be assigned to variable "dateOfHeader" = 27/05/2015

Note: I do not have any error in console

**Background on Question**

I am using scheduler control and I need to render some color based on dates.  my data source is having JSON as follow

```
 var mydatafromApi = ({
   date:01/01/2013, 
   percentage=30%,
   color = red
  },
 {
   date:02/01/2013, 
   percentage=40%
   color = blue
 });
```

Now I need to compare every date of scheduler/calendar and display background based on this JSON data

So while rendering I am storing date in custom data attribute, but to read it back I am facing issues.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `var dateOfHeader = $(this).data("data-dt");`?

Comment: I think that you will need use `.eval()` to do it. `var dateOfHeader = eval($(this).data("dt"));`.

Comment: Is it about displaying/assigning the current date?

Comment: LShetty updated my quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a javascript function to be rendered with its evaluated data in html, you need to wrap your function with `#= #` expression

```
data-dt="#= kendo.toString(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') #"
```

You should be able to get the data using jQuery data

```
$(element).data("dt");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you can use javascript [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function

```
var dateOfHeader = eval($(this).data("dt"));
```

Comment: Thanks Mladen.  But while evaluating it says "date is not defined"  - The background of problem is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308682/rendering-data-in-kendo-scheduler-control-header-dateheadertemplate/30320045#30320045

Comment: ohh, well your date variable should be replaced with actual value within single quotes `"kendo.toString('01/01/2013', 'dd/MM/yyyy')"`