# How to extend scheduler agenda view to include additional column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using Kendo Scheduler control. By default it is showing "Date","Time" and "Event" in the "Agenda" view. How to extend scheduler agenda view to include additional column as shown in attached image?

[image]

I tried templates as shown below.

```
     <script id="event-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
     <button class="edit-event" data-uid="#=uid#">Custom Column</button>
     <div>Notes: #: notes#</div>

     </div>
     </script>
```

and in Kendo initialization,i added below code

```
      views: [
      {
        type: "agenda",
        eventTemplate: $("#event-template").html()
      },
     ],
```

But it did not render as expected :(

I tried below url [Kendo Forum link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-extend-scheduler's-agenda-view-to-include-additional-customized-columns)
but it's not redirected me to any solution.

Comment: Have you done this yet?  I wondering if you've made a custom view for this yet, I'm looking to add some custom columns myself

Comment: not yet. below answer suggested for extending but did not worked as expected. keep u posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a custom view which current existing are `day`, `week`, `month`, `agenda` & `timeline`, you have to make an extended class which extend from `kendo.ui` class as Kendo UI code library example gave to us.

I encourage you to follow that example so it will work properly for `edit`, `remove` and `recurrence` events. Therefore you should look into it, yet if you have scheduler that only display events with ***simplicity*** just want to add custom column inside existing view, you can see my example [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/EbEBa/3).

I exploit scheduler data bound events and write necessary DOM to header and body of scheduler, so it will reflect just like what you had describe above.

[**Scheduler Custom View Code Library**](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-view-329353883750) - 
*recommended solution*

[**Scheduler Custom Column Alternative**](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/EbEBa/3)

Hope this help..

Comment: Thanks, that did help with the custom column, but I don't append will work for me.

          schedulerHeader.append("<th>Rating</th>"); 
          schedulerHeader.append("<th>Time</th>"); 

I need to add a column after every day in the week, for week view.  So it will be 7 extra columns.  It doesn't seem like we can just insert columns.  So I'm guessing the best was is to rewrite the whole header and column templates.  

Whats the best way to get these templates?

Comment: only issue currently i see is: it shows "rating" and "time" column in all the views, I wanted only in agenda view.

Comment: @Deepak I have fix my sample to only affect view agenda

Comment: @DanParker How is the view looks like, can you share the picture of it?

Comment: @DionDirza  What I'm trying to do is add a couple status columns, to show availibity.



<th>Monday</th><th>MyColumn1</th><th>MyColumn2</th><th>Tuesday</th>......

Comment: @DanParker I wonder what if in one day column there are multiple events, how does the status column relate to each event? There will be many breaking changes e.g event drag, event stacking CSS.. its complex for your case Dan..

Comment: @DionDirza these will be independent of events.  This will show if the person is allowed to schedule an event at that time, or that person can only schedule events with people in Group A.  It's like a side helper to know what kinds of events they can schedule.  We don't want to drag or drop to it.

Comment: @DanParker Here is a [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/EbEBa/4) to see how to add column for each day in a `Week` view. I leave the rest implementation to you.. Good luck

Comment: @DionDirza That's really cool. Only probably on a resize it creates more columns and crashes the browser

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it does not supported by kendo, kendo team says :

> Adding more columns to the "Agenda" view is not supported out of the
>   box and it will require custom solution which is out of scope of our
>   support service

But you can **extend** the **scheduler widget** like mentioned on the [forum post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-scheduler--custom-column-in-list-view#-mUkbAba6ECvaJ_21ImUrQ), there also 2 sample of way extending the widget

Answer (score 0):

```
      schedulerHeader.append("<th>Rating</th>"); 
      schedulerHeader.append("<th>Time</th>");
```

Hmm, the comment above didn't have formatting so I'll post the above again.  This helps, but I think I need to rewrite the whole template.

The example telerik keeps giving for a custom view is ok but very basic.  It only does the DataHeaderTemplate and event template, it doesn't add columns.

I'm looking for a column after every day, so I can put extra visual lines to show the status.  Sounds like I need to rewrite the column and header templates.  I don't see any good examples of that

Comment: Thanks Dan, let us know if u able to achieve it, and do share the dojo links.